# How to add a column keeping incremental unique -letter(s)- for each record to a table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server 2008 like

```
Id  Name      Volume
1   Jack        20
2   John        20
3   White       40
... (23 more)
27   Jennifer   12
28   Brown      33
29   Brown      55
... (23 more)
53   Alex       67
53   Smith      15
53   Mary       73
```

What I want is to add a column to this table, which keeps unique letter(s) for each different id. Example output:

```
Id  Name      Volume   LetterKey
1   Jack        20        A
2   John        20        B
3   White       40        C
... (23 more)          (...Z)
27   Jennifer   12        AA  
28   Brown      33        AB
29   Brown      55        AC
... (23 more)         (...AZ)
53   Alex       67        BA
53   Smith      15        BB
53   Mary       73        BC
...                   (...BZ)
```

We do not need 3-digit letters, ZZ would be the last possible one. I could not find a proper way to add such a column to the table. I appreciate if someone helps me with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only a two character code, you can use `row_number()` and some character arithmetic:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select ((case when seqnum > 26
              then char(ascii('A') + seqnum / 26 - 1)
              else ''
         end) + 
        char(ascii('A') + seqnum % 26) 
       )
from t
```

Comment: You were some seconds faster :-)